# How to add slim.batch_norm after custom ops/layer in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf-slim, batch-normalization, tensorflow-slim

I have a function that aims to build an architecture as

```
Input(x) -> o=My_ops(x,128) -> o=slim.batch_norm(o)
```

So, my function is

```
def _build_block(self, x, name, is_training=True):
  with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
    o = my_ops(x, 256)
    batch_norm_params = {
      'decay': 0.9997,
      'epsilon': 1e-5,
      'scale': True,
      'updates_collections': tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS,
      'fused': None,  # Use fused batch norm if possible.
      'is_training': is_training
    }
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.batch_norm], **batch_norm_params) as bn:
      return slim.batch_norm(o)
```

Am I right? Can I set `is_training` as in a function above? If not, could you fix to help me?

Comment: Do you really need `arg_scope` for just one `batch_norm`?

Comment: Because i have to use the customer setting like is_training=True, decay 0.9997, so I use it to pass bn parameters. Do you have another way?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is ok. And yes, you can set `is_training` into `slim.batch_norm` like that.

But your code looks unnecessarily complicated to me. Here's an equivalent version:

```
def _build_block(self, x, name, is_training=True):
  with tf.variable_scope(name):
    o = my_ops(x, 256)
    return slim.batch_norm(o, decay=0.9997, epsilon=1e-5, scale=True, is_training=is_training)
```

Note that I dropped `arg_scope` (because it's main use-case is to *repeat* the same arguments to *multiple* layers, you have only one), omitted `updates_collections=tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` and `fused=None` (because these are the default values), dropped `as scope` (because it's unused).